# Dash is empty, reinstallation doesn't help

Tags: 12.10, unity-dash

I used

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

but dash home didn't show anything. I reinstalled, and the same result.

What should I install to get it to work?

I only got a small icon `home` at the bottom center.

Answer (score 0):

Same here.  Installed Ubuntu Server 12.10 in VMWare Player 5.0.1, then installed GUI with

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

and now i can't open any apps, dash is empty, no panels, etc

I was able to resolve it by clicking the software center icon and installing `unity-lens-applications` and `unity-lens-files`. I also figured out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> opens a terminal after installing those two packages through the software center. I issued the command `unity --reset` from the terminal.

Comment: I was able to resolve it by clicking the software center icon and installing unity-lens-applications and unity-lens-files

i also figured out ctrl + alt + T opens a terminal
after installing those two files through the software center i issued the command

    unity --reset

from the terminal